# Disable coupons for sale products in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, conditional-statements, product, price

Hey I want to disable coupons for sale products in Opencart.

I found coupon code and here is list of "if-s" when the coupon is not working... I have to add here the condition that when product is on discount `$status = false;`

But I dont know how to check if the product have special price...

```
if ($coupon_query->row['total'] > $this->cart->getSubTotal()) {
    $status = false;
}
$coupon_history_query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "coupon_history` ch WHERE ch.coupon_id = '" . (int)$coupon_query->row['coupon_id'] . "'");

if ($coupon_query->row['uses_total'] > 0 && ($coupon_history_query->row['total'] >= $coupon_query->row['uses_total'])) {
    $status = false;
}

if ($coupon_query->row['logged'] && !$this->customer->getId()) {
    $status = false;
}
```

Comment: Which file is this that you found the code in and which version of opencart are you using

Answer (score 4):

This is for version 2.3.0.2

In your file `catalog/model/extension/total/coupon.php` look for the function `public function getTotal($total)` :

next to the line

```
$this->load->language('extension/total/coupon');
```

Add

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

Next search `$discount = 0;` in same function. Before `$discount = 0;` add

```
$product_details = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);
if($product_details['special']) {
    continue;
}
```

This will skip applying discount to products that have special price and will apply for other products in the cart.

Comment: This saved me lots of time, thanks! Best to do this in a vqmod/ocmod modification though, to ensure future updates are painless. Or less painful anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code, it works pretty well, but when I've add this I noticed another bug that appeared. When I add products that are not on sale and products that are on sale, the discount value is not correct. The type of coupon value is set to fixed price.
Example :
Discount coupon - 20USD
Product 1 - 10USD - On Sale
Product 2 - 20USD - On Sale
Product 3 - 100USD - Not on sale

Discount coupon value appear in checkout like : -17,65 or something.
This is the check that I made in coupon.php

```
if ($status) {
  if ($coupon_info['type'] == 'F') {
    $discount = $coupon_info['discount'] * ($product['total'] / $sub_total);
  } elseif ($coupon_info['type'] == 'P') {
    $discount = $product['total'] / 100 * $coupon_info['discount'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look for `foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {` , you nedd to add the same codes above after `if (in_array($product['product_id'], $coupon_info['product'])) {` again.